# Specify access log directory in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

How do I specify the access log directory in JBoss 7.1.1? At the moment the access log is being created in the JBOSS-HOME/standalone/log/default-host directory and I want it to be in JBOSS-HOME/standalone/log directory?

Answer (score 4):

For the access log you just need to specify a `.` (dot) in the `path` element.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <access-log rotate="true">
            <directory path="." relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir"/>
        </access-log>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update “standalone.xml” file like below, the emphasis is "file relative-to"

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="/log/server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

A part of the solution given by gaara, which is valid, you can also leave the standalone.xml as it comes by default:

```
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
```

And set the JBoss environment property jboss.server.log.dir in the startup script, for example:

./standalone.sh -Djboss.server.log.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log

<del>(or even better: add it in the JAVA_OPTS of your own startup script).</del>

(or even better: add it in the JAVA_OPTS of the standalone.conf).